# copy template of one html file to others without typing the same code again

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, visual-studio-code

i am creating a e-commerce website using html/css. what i am trying to achieve is that i need same template for all product pages after clicking on the product. And i want to do this without actually coding every page using html and css. is there anyway to do this?

i tried to code all pages but that will be impossible to finsh if i keep on doing it, i want an effective way of doing this.

Comment: For that, you can use 1 template only. So everytime a user clicks on a product, you should retrieve its data from the database then display it.

Comment: search the web for `javascript template engine`

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain JS to achieve the same or can use JS libraries like React JS, Angular JS, etc. for versatility. But all of these would require a good knowledge of coding.

And, to skip coding, I'll suggest you use WordPress + WooCommerce, all the required features are free and you don't have to code a single line, it's all GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Javascript for this. The easy thing will be to work with a Javascript library called **React**.

In react you will make a component called a product card! and now you can pass your data to the product card by mapping the product list. You don't need to write product data showing HTML CSS for every product. Just write it one time and use it as many times as you want with React.

Here is the [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)